# CAN sockets in erlang

Tags: erlang, can-bus

I'm writing a test program for an application on a CAN connected device.

I'd like to use Erlang for that, because I already wrote similar test programs for other kinds of networks, and the test application itself should only encode and decode data in a given protocol format, which can be done easily in erlang.

Under linux, the CAN interface can be seen as a network device, and a CAN connection is a kind of socket. I've already found a python module for that (which would be my second choice), but nothing on erlang.

Does anybody have experience on interfacing erlang with CAN? It's nearly impossible to find something on google, because of course "can" is a common word with another meaning, and erlang "can" a lot of things.

Comment: 1) "I like to use Erlang because the task can be easily done in that language" ... 2) "I have no idea how to do the task in Elang and I can't find any resources about it anywhere!" Given 2), how on Earth did you come up with 1)? The sensible solution is to use C.

Comment: @Lundin once you have the connection to the CAN bus, Erlang is a great tool for the task he wants to solve, while C would only be useful for the actual driver part and not sensible at all for the rest of the task.

Comment: What I wanted to say: I have some experience with Erlang, not so much with CAN, the embedded application is written in C++, but the test programs which run on my PC can be written in a higher level language. Erlang would be my first choice, with Python as a fallback.

Comment: @GB People have been using both Common Test and QuickCheck/Proper for driving tests of external systems from within Erlang, with great success, so you shouldn't have to do too much work apart from the test code itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Googling for `erlang "can bus"` gives you better hits. I know several people have been using Erlang for this sort of thing for a long time. See https://github.com/tonyrog/can and https://github.com/tonyrog/canopen for starters.